# Using Regex to validate a string looking lke sd1258 (Two charaters and 3-4 digits)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to construct a Regex Expression to be used to verify if an input is a valid flightcode. A A valid flightcode looks like two characters and then three or four digits. It's posssible to start the digits with zeroes, but at least onedigit must be 1-9.
Valid codes are eg DE1258 , DE012, SK4589, fr0020 or us0001

I have tried the following solution but it doesn't work.

```
Regex RegexObj = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]{2}$\d\d\d\d");
```

Comment: Try putting the `$` symbol after the last `\d`?

Comment: As a side-note, `$` means the end of the string, so there can't be anything afterwards.

Comment: This definitely isn't C.

Answer (score 2):

The following Regex will do what you want

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}(?!0{4})\d{3,4}$
```

The reason this works is the (!?0{4}) is a negative lookahead. The regular expression will continue past this point only if the sub-expression does not match.